# ASP.Net MVC. How automatically persist relational data using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This are POCO Code First Classes:

```
class Contact{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Phone> phones{get; set;}
}

class Phone{
    [Key]
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string phone_type {get; set;}
    public string phone_number {get; set;}
    public Contact contact { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to persist it on DB.

This is the controller:

the binded "contact" instance does contains a Contact with a List phones with a lot of phones.

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind()] Contact contact) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(contact).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(contact);
}
```

But this code only persist the Contact instance on db. The Phones table still empty.

Is there any configuration to automatically persist the related "phones" data on the db, Or must it be coded by hand?

for those interested, the view is like this (simplified):

```
@model SGD.Models.Contact
Name:    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
Phones: <div id="phones"></div>
```

where the #phones div is populated with this partial with a incremental index.

```
<input name="phones[@index].id" type="hidden" />
<input name="phones[@index].phone_type" />
<input name="phones[@index].phone_number" />
```

Comment: Please show how you are adding/removing phones in your view

Comment: @octavioccl I added the simplified view code. But i'm sure that the controller binds the data correctly from the view. the problem here is just persist it on db.

Comment: Did you debug your action to make sure the phones come with the contact?

Comment: @octavioccl Yes. i'm sure. i debugged and watch this variable. It contains the data.  http://imgur.com/a/FchXP (this is real screenshot, quite more complicated than the simple example above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I was reading if you just change the `State` to `Modified` in the root entity, the related entities don't change their states ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)):

> Note that if the entity being attached has references to other
>   entities that are not yet tracked, then these new entities will
>   attached to the context in the Unchanged state—they will not
>   automatically be made Modified. If you have multiple entities that
>   need to be marked Modified you should set the state for each of these
>   entities individually.

Try using [TryUpdateModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx). I'm not totally sure if it update related entities, but it should if your model binds the related entity.

```
var contact= db.Contacts.Include(c=>c.Addresses).FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id==contact.Id);
TryUpdateModel(contact);
```

What I always use in this cases is a ViewModel  and I map it later to one of my entities using [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)

Also there is a  3rd party library ([GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff)) that allow you to save an entire detached Model/Entity, with child Entities and Lists, to the database without writing the code to do it.